# How to Force Docker to release storage space after manual delete of file in volumes and containers?

Tags: docker

I have few issues with storage spaces. I deleted few big files such as log files (after find unix of big files).

The problem is that delete manually some file of Docker (in /var/lib/docker/...). After deletion of Docker files, I can see that the space left does not change. Docker does not release space.

I restart the service Docker and I the problem persit.

How can I force Docker to release space from (devicemapper, volume, images, ...) ?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45798076/562769

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker cleanup job is rather non-existing and you are basically in charge of doing it yourself. There are ways of doing that as pointed out in [this blog-post](https://lebkowski.name/docker-volumes/), yet I rather use third-party scripts, e.g.: [docker-clean](https://github.com/ZZROTDesign/docker-clean) to clean up some of the mess docker leaves behind.

Answer (score 27):

With recent versions of Docker you can see the space used with:

`docker system df`

and prune it with:

`docker system prune`

The above command combines the prune command that exists for volumes, containers, networks and images:

`docker volume prune`

`docker container prune`

`docker image prune`

`docker network prune`

All of these have a `--help option`.

-o-

On older versions of Docker I ran the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Remove dead containers (and their volumes)
docker ps -f status=dead --format '{{ .ID }}' | xargs -r docker rm -v
# Remove dangling volumes
docker volume ls -qf dangling=true | xargs -r docker volume rm
# Remove untagged ("<none>") images
docker images --digests --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}@{{.Digest}}' | sed -rne 's/([^>]):<none>@/\1@/p' | xargs -r docker rmi
# Remove dangling images
docker images -qf dangling=true | xargs -r docker rmi
# Remove temporary files
rm -f /var/lib/docker/tmp/*
```

Comment: Be careful though. `docker prune` is very greedy and may delete even too much. I didn't expect stopped containers to be deleted, rather just their image.

Comment: @k0pernikus I can confirm that on version 18.09.1 you receive a verbose message beforehand: 
WARNING! This will remove:
        - all stopped containers
        - all networks not used by at least one container
        - all dangling images
        - all dangling build cache
Are you sure you want to continue?

Answer (score 7):

This depends on what version of docker you are using, If you are using >1.13 then you can use:

```
docker system df
```

and

```
docker system df -v
```

^^These will show where disk space is being utilized.

You can cleanup using `prune` commands:

```
docker system prune -af
```

^^ This prunes everything & is the most destructive.
Or you can use `docker image prune` or `docker volume prune` etc.